# How to do top-posting with mutt?

Tags: mutt

When replying to emails, I want it to be like this:

```
Hi, Foobar, very good idea indeed.
---
Regards, Username

On Jan 15, Wed FooBar wrote:
>blah blah
> blah blah blah
```

But instead mutt does this by default, and I haven't found an option to change it:

```
On Jan 15, Wed Foobar wrote:
>blah blah
>blaaaaaaah

Ok, glad to hear that, see you soon, bye.
---
Regards, Username
```

So, how do I do it?

Answer (score 5):

From `man muttrc` (it is self-explanatory):

> sig_on_top
>        Type: boolean
>        Default: no
>
> If  set,  the  signature  will be included before any quoted or forwarded text.  It is **strongly** recommended that you
>   do not set this variable
>                     unless you really know what you are doing, and are prepared to take some heat from netiquette guardians

<sub>Note: you are doing no-one any favours by top posting.</sub>

Comment: `Note: you are doing no-one any favours by top posting.` - yes, can't be stressed enough.